# New Email Unsubscribe Feature

Tags: discussion, email, announcement

We are happy to announce a new [email unsubscribe feature](https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/current) for all Stack Overflow accounts. We believe it’s important to provide everyone with a simple solution to control the types of emails they receive.

[image: New settings view]

#### What is changing

We maintain separate Sales and Marketing platforms that are used to send business-related emails, which are designed to promote our paid products to potential business customers. These platforms operate independently from the account system used across the Stack Exchange network and have their own email preference center which manages our business-related emails.

Starting today, you will notice a new control toggle at the top of the Promotional section under your email settings. This allows you to better manage your email subscriptions across all Stack Overflow systems.

#### Why we introduced this new feature

With the growth of Stack Overflow for Teams, we are seeing more and more Stack Exchange users express interest in our business-related products and content, which is increasing the amount of overlap seen between these two systems. This feature is an effort to ensure our emailing practices match your expectations.

#### What the new feature does

Turning this toggle off will unsubscribe you from our Features & Announcements emails as well as The Overflow Newsletter. Additionally, this will sync your request across our Sales and Marketing email platforms and unsubscribe any records with a matching email address within those systems.

#### What the new feature doesn’t do

Turning this toggle from off to on will not resubscribe you to any email buckets. All promotional email buckets have been deactivated when the unsubscribe request was sent and will not be reactivated on your behalf. All email buckets will need to be reactivated manually. Additionally, interacting with the promotional unsubscribe toggle will not add your email address or any PII into new systems.

#### Design improvements

While we were making changes to functionality on this page, we’ve also introduced a fully responsive design that will scale to any device or window size. The visuals have also been improved and switched to our unified design system, [Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/).

Comment: So, what exactly does it mean, if all of the sub options are disabled but promotional is enabled? Secondly, is it enabled by default? (it was enabled for me, even though previously I had the others disabled)

Comment: @KevinB It was not enabled for me.

Comment: @KevinB If one enables Promotional but disables Features & Announcements and The Overflow we won't send their account anything community related. At the same time it means that it is possible that they could get business-related emails about the paid products if their email address is in one of those systems. Their email addresses could get into those systems if they download marketing ebooks, register for marketing webinars, etc. In other words, having Promotional enabled does not mean that one will get anything.

Comment: @KevinB It was also enabled for me and I'm pretty sure I had all email notifications settings disabled.

Comment: So, it's not possible to enable "Features & Announcements" or "The Overflow" without enabling unrelated and vague "Promotional" emails...? Well, I guess it works for me. I'll just disable everything.

Comment: the whole... toggle not really being a toggle thing makes this UI "work" in an unexpected way. Generally, you'd expect toggling something on to do something, but in this case, if you've previously toggled it off, toggling it on, does nothing... Wouldn't a different UI entirely be better here? I understand it's not really possible to directly include the "opt back in" bit here since it's manual due to the nature of unsubscribing, but leaving it a toggle when that toggle works inconsistently is... messy. Once subscribed, it's just an unsub button.

Comment: @yivi It is totally up to you if you want to subscribe or unsubscribe. At the same time, the marketing systems we use have their own email preference center. So if one is getting emails from those systems, they can unsubscribe from these emails separately using the unsubscribe link that each email should have in its footer.

Comment: I second KevinB's comment above; a toggle doesn't make any sense at all here if toggling back on does... nothing. It should be a one-time button that disables, or something similar which clearly shows that this action isn't reversible by the user.

Comment: My meta user settings for email were different than my main Stack Overflow account. Promotional emails were turned off on the main account, but turned on for the meta account. I'm not sure if that has any effect on things because I don't recall seeing any emails from Stack Exchange.

Comment: @BoogaRoo That... cannot be possible. Attempting to edit your profile from here (Meta Stack Overflow) redirects you to your profile on the main Stack Overflow site. There's no separate Meta profile for Stack Overflow users. Do you mean [Meta.SE], which does have a separate user profile?

Comment: For me the top toggle button is set to on, the below two are off. Does it means I did unsubscribe already from elsewhere?

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe it was caching, but I thought that initially the page "https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/12345678" had promotional emails "enabled" but the page "https://stackoverflow.com/users/email/settings/12345678" did not. I enabled it then disabled it in "main." Now they're in sync and I guess everything's fine now(or maybe I could use some more coffee).

Comment: *"All promotional email buckets have been deactivated when the unsubscribe request was sent and will not be reactivated on your behalf. All email buckets will need to be reactivated manually"* this does not seem to make any sense to me. It's just a lot more manual work on both ends for no reason, I'm really confused.

Answer (score 51):

> **What the new feature doesn’t do**
>
> Turning this toggle from off to on will not resubscribe you to any email buckets.

Wait, *what*? You mean that if I turn the toggle "off", it will unsubscribe me, but if I turn the toggle back "on", it won't re-subscribe me? This makes absolutely no sense. I am reading it right here in black-and-white, and yet I am still convinced that I must be misunderstanding it. There is no way I would ever understand this if I were just looking at the user interface on my profile page.

It, uh, well, it does say on the page next to the toggle option:

> You can turn them off whenever you want.

which is great copy—it's clear, comforting, and reassuring. But if it means to imply that I *cannot* turn them back *on* whenever I want, well, it's very misleading copy, and a very bad user interface.

How do you expect users to understand that this is a "one-time-use-only" toggle? It doesn't say that anywhere on the page. And, if it is true, then it should not be styled as a toggle. It should be a button that I can click once to unsubscribe, and then the button enters a disabled state (preferably with a tooltip or some help text elsewhere on the page that explains what I should do now if I want to re-subscribe).

In general, this entire announcement and feature is very confusing. The whole thing seems very poorly thought out, and even more poorly communicated. It isn't clear what the default option is, what all the different states actually mean, whether it's possible to subscribe to some without the others, what happens to my personal information, or…well, anything.

The title and the idea—being able to unsubscribe separately from "promotional" content—seems like a great idea. But I don't understand how it's been implemented, what the options means, how they work in combination, or what the caveats are. Not a good sign; if I can't understand it after reading this announcement carefully multiple times, how would a new user who *doesn't* read Meta be expected to understand it?

I am also frustrated because, when I visited my profile to see what options were available to me, I see that options I distinctly remembered turning off in the past were re-enabled. (Specifically, options to email me the contents of my inbox. I have never wanted that, in the entire history of my having an account here.) So, it seems like these changes discarded my previously stated preferences for other options. I find that irritating. It's hard enough to study and understand the meaning of these options. It's even more frustrating if my preferences aren't remembered and I have to keep resetting them.

Comment: Cody, we just looked at our logs, and it looks like you were opted back in to Inbox communications when you joined AskUbuntu in Nov. This is a bug, and I was just able to repro it. Thanks for bringing to our attention. We will fix.

Comment: Currently there is no way to visualise all subscription preferences directly in one's Stack Overflow account, as a result we decided to not automatically reactivate any buckets when the master toggle is turned back on.

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for surfacing this bug to us. We've just pushed a fix that addresses communication preferences being overwritten. Moving forward, joining a new community will no longer reset your email or notification preferences.