# Is there a way to view whether a 'watched tag' notification was sent by Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, email, tag-watching

Our community uses a [Discourse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_%28software%29) category that is subscribed to specific Stack Overflow tags to improve visibility of questions within the community. At some point in the past year, these notification emails have stopped being delivered to Discourse and the Discourse logs show that no emails were rejected from the Discourse side.

Is there a way to view whether the 'watched tag' notifications were sent from the Stack Overflow side? Alternatively, any other ideas on how to debug the issue occurring?

Comment: What community?

Comment: The Chapel programming language community: https://chapel.discourse.group/c/notifications/stack-overflow/

Comment: something rings a bell that changes were made in this context, maybe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370216 or https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413744